# Let $X$ denote the number of instances in which a head is followed by a tail. Find variance of $X$.

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, variance

> Suppose $n (n\ge 2)$ coins are tossed independently in a row. Let $X$ denote the number of instances in which a head is followed by a tail. Find variance of $X$.

I tried using indicator random variables.

Let $Y_n$ be the event of the $n^{th}$ toss being a head and the $n+1^{th}$ toss being a tail. $P(Y_n)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{4} \forall n$. Let $I_n$ be the indicator $\text{R.V.}$ for $Y_n$.

I found $E(X)=\displaystyle\frac{(n-1)}{4}$

I'm struggling with $E(X^2)$. The entire calculation becomes too messy and doesn't seem right. I'm getting a quadratic equation of $n$, which is definitely heading in the wrong direction.

Can someone please guide me with this problem? Thank you.

Comment: You can still use linearity, it's just more work.  Use the fact that $\text {Var}(X)=E[X^2]-E[X]^2$.

Comment: That's what I've been doing. But the solution for $E(X^2)$ produces a very messy equation. The answer to the problem is $\frac{n+1}{16}$, so I think there's a simpler way of doing it that I am missing.

Comment: $E[X^2]$ isn't messy, really.  Remember $I_m^2=I_m$ and it's easy to evaluate $E[I_kI_j]$ for $i\neq j$.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
E[X^2]
  &= E[(I_1+\dots+I_{n-1})^2]
\\&= E\left[\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sum_{\ell=1}^{n-1}I_kI_\ell\right]
\\&= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sum_{\ell=1}^{n-1}E\left[I_kI_\ell\right]
\\&= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sum_{\ell=1}^{n-1}P(Y_k\cap Y_\ell)
\end{align}
You just need to figure out how to evaluate $P(Y_k\cap Y_\ell)$, for each $k,\ell\in \{1,\dots,n-1\}$. There are several cases to consider.

1. If $k=\ell$, then $P(Y_k\cap Y_\ell)=P(Y_k)=1/4$.
2. If $k=\ell+1$, then $P(Y_k\cap Y_\ell)=0$, because $Y_k$ requires a tails at position $k+1$, but $Y_{k+1}$ requires a heads at position $k+1$. The same is true when $k=\ell-1$.
3. In all other cases, the events $Y_k$ and $Y_\ell$ involve disjoint sets of coins, so the events are independent, and $P(Y_k\cap Y_\ell)=P(Y_k)P(Y_\ell)=(1/4)(1/4)=1/16$.

In the summation $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sum_{\ell=1}^{n-1}P(Y_k\cap Y_\ell)$, there are $n-1$ terms corresponding to case $1$, there are $2(n-2)$ terms corresponding to case $2$, while the remaining $(n-1)^2-(n-1)-2(n-2)$ terms fall in case $3$. Therefore,

$$
E[X^2]=(n-1)\cdot \frac14+[(n-1)^2-(n-1)-2(n-2)]\cdot \frac1{16}
$$

Finally, you can show that $\text{Var }X=E[X^2]-(E[X])^2$ simplifies to $(n+1)/16$. However, there is no quick explanation which matches the simplicity of this final answer. Sometimes in math, you need to plod your way through a complicated looking summation, it is unavoidable. You should not say "the entire calculation becomes too messy and doesn't seem right," you should accept that some calculations will be messy.

Comment: Thanks. I was just looking to see if there's a simpler way of thinking about this problem that I had overlooked. Now I see there isn't. Appreciate your effort and help.

Answer (score 1):

For $ n \ge 2$, let $ {\left({X}_{i}\right)}_{1  \leqslant  i  \leqslant  n}$ be i.i.d random variables and $ f \colon  {\mathbb{R}}^{2} \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}$ be any bounded measurable function, finally, let

\begin{equation}X = \sum _{i = 1}^{n-1} f \left({X}_{i} , {X}_{i+1}\right)\end{equation}

Then

\begin{equation}\text{Var} \left(X\right) = \left(n-1\right) {\nu}+2 \left(n-2\right) \left({\xi}-{{\mu}}^{2}\right)\end{equation}

where

\begin{equation}{\mu} = E \left[f \left({X}_{1} , {X}_{2}\right)\right], \quad  {\nu} = \text{Var} \left(f \left({X}_{1} , {X}_{2}\right)\right), \quad  {\xi} = E \left[f \left({X}_{1} , {X}_{2}\right) f \left({X}_{2} , {X}_{3}\right)\right] \left[n  \geqslant  3\right]\end{equation}

Indeed, it is clear that $E \left(X\right) = \left(n-1\right) {\mu}$ and

\begin{equation}\begin{array}{rcl}E \left[{X}^{2}\right]&=&\displaystyle  \sum _{i = 0}^{n-1} \sum _{j = 0}^{n-1} E \left[f \left({X}_{i} , {X}_{i+1}\right) f \left({X}_{j} , {X}_{j+1}\right)\right]\\
&=&\displaystyle  \sum  \sum _{\left|i-j\right| = 0}+\sum  \sum _{\left|i-j\right| = 1}+\sum  \sum _{\left|i-j\right|  \geqslant  2}\\
&=&\left(n-1\right) \left({\nu}+{{\mu}}^{2}\right)+2 \left(n-2\right) {\xi}+\left({\left(n-1\right)}^{2}-\left(n-1\right)-2 \left(n-2\right)\right) {{\mu}}^{2}\\
&=&\left(n-1\right) {\nu}+2 \left(n-2\right) {\xi}+{\left(E \left[X\right]\right)}^{2}-2 \left(n-2\right) {{\mu}}^{2}
\end{array}\end{equation}

which implies the result.

In our case, we have $ f \left({X}_{i} , {X}_{i+1}\right) = 1$ if
$ \left({X}_{i} , {X}_{i+1}\right) = \left(0 , 1\right)$ and $0$ otherwise, where
$ {X}_{i} = 1$ if the $ i$ -th coin is a tail and $0$
otherwise. It follows that

\begin{equation} {\mu} = \frac{1}{4} \qquad  {\nu} = \frac{3}{16} \qquad  {\xi} = 0\end{equation}

Hence

\begin{equation}\text{Var} \left(X\right) = \frac{3 \left(n-1\right)}{16}-\frac{2 \left(n-2\right)}{16} = \frac{n+1}{16}\end{equation}

Comment: this really should be elaborated a bit more....

Comment: @Mike I elaborated, as requested.

Answer (score 0):

> $\displaystyle  \begin{array}{{>{\displaystyle}l}}
> Actually,\ you\ can\ avoid\ calculating\ E\left[ X^{2}\right]\\
> \\
> Let\ Y_{i} \ be\ the\ event\ of\ the\ i^{th} \ toss\ being\ a\ head\ and\ the\ ( i+1)^{th} \ toss\ being\ a\ tail.\ \\
> \ \\
> Let\ I_{i} \ be\ the\ indicator\ R.V.\ for\ Y_{i} .\ \\
> Let\ p\ =\ Pr( I_{i} \ =\ 1) \ =\ Pr( Y_{i}) =\frac{1}{4} \ ,\ i\ =\ 1,2...n-1.\\
> \\
> Then,\ Var( I_{i}) \ =p( 1-p) \ =\ \frac{3}{16}\\
> \\
> We\ can\ write\\
> \\
> Var( I_{1} +I_{2} \ +\ ...\ I_{n-1}) \ \ =\ \sum _{i=1}^{i=n-1} Var( I_{i}) \ +\ 2\sum \sum _{i< j} Cov( I_{i} ,\ I_{j})\\
> Now,\ \\
> \\
> Cov( I_{i} ,\ I_{j}) \ =\ 0,\ j\neq \ i+1\ ( \ Because\ tosses\ are\ independent)\\
> Cov( I_{i} ,\ I_{j}) \ =\ \frac{-1}{16} \ ,\ j=\ i+1\ ( this\ value\ can\ be\ calculated\ easily)\\
> \\
> \\
> Since\ there\ are\ n-2\ consecutive\ I_{i} ,\ I_{i+1} \ pairs,\ we\ have\\
> \\
> Var( I_{1} +I_{2} \ +\ ...\ I_{n-1}) \ =\ ( n-1)\frac{3}{16} \ +\ 2( n-2)\frac{-1}{16} \ =\ \frac{n+1}{16}\\
> \\
> \\
> \\
> \end{array}$